# Is there a good reason to use T-count minimization for circuits executed on current IBM open quantum systems (real hardware)?

Tags: error-correction, architecture, ibm-quantum-devices, clifford-group

As far as I understood from a series of papers, minimizing the `T-count` in `Clifford+T` circuits is essential for fault-tolerant quantum computing:

> *While techniques such as magic state distillation and  injection allow for fault-tolerant implementation of T gates, they typically require an  order of magnitude more resources than Clifford gates*

For example see [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.07330.pdf) and [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1903.10477.pdf).

But do I understand correctly that while minimizing `T-count` (incl. in `Clifford+T` circuits) does not give a significant gain for the current **IBM** [open quantum systems](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/docs/manage/backends/#open-quantum-systems) (real hardware, not simulations!), in particular, due to the fact that at the moment `T` gate (like `T†`, `U1`/`P` and `RZ` gates)

> *can be implemented virtually in hardware via framechanges (i.e. **at zero error and duration**)*

See the [documentation](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.PhaseGate.html)

Comment: I don't know the specifics of IBM hardware (hence this not being an answer), but yes, my general understanding is the T-gate optimisation is for fault-tolerant scenarios. At the level of physical qubits, you can directly implement any unitary, so why would you go for a long sequence of Hadamard + T to approximately synthesise it? I don't know a reason.

Comment: @DaftWullie: On IBM Q you can use U3 which allows to implement any one qubit operation, so you really do not have to do decomposition to H, S and T gates. However, only $U1(\theta)$ gate (in fact $Rz(\theta)$ gate up to global phase) and $Rx(\pi/2)$ are physically implemented one qubit gates. So, some decomposition to basic gate set is necessary and I would expect that $Rz$ for arbitrary angle is non-Clifford gate and hence number of such gates matters.

Comment: T gates, or any phase gate, is a virtual gate that comes for free today. This is different than the fault tolerant regime.

Comment: A small addition: **IBM Q systems** not the only quantum computers in which the `Z`-rotation gate is implemented virtually on the hardware level, there are others, for example, [**QSCOUT**](https://www.sandia.gov/quantum/Projects/QSCOUT_Jaqal.html): "Single-qubit `Z` gates executed **virtually** by adjusting the reference clocks of individual qubits". Accordingly, there apparently also does not require the minimization of the T-count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it doesn't make sense to minimize T count on NISQ hardware. As you note, T gates don't even have a cost because they are done virtually by updating the rotation frame of later operations. No reason to minimize things that are free! If anything, you should be **maximizing** their use.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! I suspected that it was so, but I was afraid that I did not understand something. With your authority you dispelled these fears!

Answer (score 0):

Every gate has a cost because each gate of NISQ computers are noisy so each one introduces a little bit of error. This means that if you use fewer gates to do the same task, you'll end up with less error. Also, coherence time is limited so one can only perform so many gates...meaning that if you reduce your gate-count, you are able to do more meaningful computation than if you didn't minimize the gate count.